# My jscorllpane doesn't work

Tags: java, jscrollpane

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
    JTextField tf_input;
    JTextArea ta_output;
    JScrollPane sp_taop;

    private class klis implements KeyListener{    
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                //System.out.println("enter");  //debug
                if (!tf_input.getText().isEmpty()){
                    String input = tf_input.getText();

                    ta_output.setText(ta_output.getText()+input+'\n');

                    System.out.println(input);  //debug
                    System.out.println("ok!");  //debug
                    sp_taop.validate(); 
                    tf_input.setText(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    Gui(){
        System.out.println("hello");
        inti();
        render();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void inti() {
        setSize(800, 600);
        //text field input
        tf_input = new JTextField();
        tf_input.setSize(550, 24);
        tf_input.addKeyListener(new klis());
        //text Area
        ta_output = new JTextArea("hello World\n",30,60);
        ta_output.setSize(ta_output.getPreferredSize());
        ta_output.setLineWrap(true);
        ta_output.setEditable(false);
        sp_taop = new JScrollPane();
        sp_taop.add(ta_output);
        sp_taop.setSize(ta_output.getSize().width+20,ta_output.getSize().height);
        sp_taop.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    }   
    private void render() {
        Panel p = new Panel(null);

        ta_output.setLocation(0, 0);
        sp_taop.setLocation(10, 10);
        tf_input.setLocation(10, (sp_taop.getSize().height+20));
        ta_output.repaint();

        //adding
        p.add(sp_taop);
        p.add(tf_input);
        add(p);
    }
}
```

I'm running this on java 1.7.0_25 on vbox 4.3.4 lUbuntu

The problem is that the jscroll is not updating itself! What should i do?
I've been searching google for hours now and i have not found anything close to what I am looking for.

By the way sorry about the plain code it was hard to explain the problem without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `JScrollPane#add`, this is not how scroll panes work, instead try using [`JScrollPane#setViewportView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29)

Take a look at [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Don't add you text field to another container.  Components can only have a single parent, so adding it to a second container will remove it from the first.

On a side note.  I would avoid the use of `KeyListener`, text components have the capacity to consume key events, meaning that your listener may not actually be notified.  Also, if it is called, the component will be in the middle of of mutation operation (it will be trying to update it's model) which can cause unexpected issues and possibly dirty updates.

I might be tempted to use a `DocumentListener` in this case, but you would need to test it.

I would also avoid the use of `null` layouts.  To start with, you won't be able to effect the position of the text field within the context of the scroll pane as the scroll pane uses it's own layout manager.

Moreover, the differences between OS, video drivers and fonts makes the potential rendering outputs endless.  Layout managers take out the guess work when dealing with these situations